# How to pre-populate a form using the object-oriented approach of Mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, oop, mysqli

I am trying to pre-populate a php form using the Object Oriented PHP Mysqli method. The examples I have found online are mostly procedural, and of no assistance. I can get the results to echo on the page, but once I try to use the echo tag in the input field it no longer works. The whole page is blank, and there are no errors.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from Pages where ID = 10";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = array();


while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    if (!empty($_POST['PTitle']) && $_POST['PTitle'] == $row['id']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["PType"].'">'.$row["PTitle"].', '.$row["PType"].', '.$row["PContent"].', '.$row["POrder"].', '.$row["PTitle"].'</option>';

}


//$mysqli->close();
?>  

<form>
  Name: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['PTitle]?>"/> </br>

</form>
```

Here is what I understood about it being outside the form, and while loop.

```
 require 'dor.php';

$sql = "SELECT * from Pages where ID = 10";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = array();


while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    if (!empty($_POST['PTitle']) && $_POST['PTitle'] == $row['id']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["PType"].'">'.$row["PTitle"].', '.$row["PType"].', '.$row["PContent"].', '.$row["POrder"].', '.$row["PTitle"].'</option>';


<form>
  Name: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['PTitle]?>"/> </br>

</form>

}


//$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: O am pretty sure that there _are_ errors actually. You just have to look at the right place: _in your http servers error log file_.

Comment: Your `<input>` is after your `while()` loop. Also, you are echoing your `<option>` before/outside your `<form>`

Comment: Think how your code will execute line by line and produce what result and you will know the problem.

Comment: @arkascha [07-Apr-2016 06:10:07 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PTitle in /home/liberreta/public_html/adm/latest.php on line 86
[07-Apr-2016 06:11:00 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PTitle in /home/liberreta/public_html/adm/latest.php on line 85

Comment: @Sean same error if I put it inside, and my error log doesnt update

Comment: The single `<option>` tag you output is not wrapped by a `<select>` tag, so invalid. The Notices you see in the error log file are not warnings, they only state that `$_POST['PTitle']` is not set at all. Which is not surprising, since that code apparently is meant to create the html form, not to process it. Try looking at the source code of the "empty" page your browser shows (right click > show source or similar) and check if it _really_ does not contain anything at all.

Comment: @SameerJain having written this line by line, I can ensure you looking at it again is of no benefit :)

Comment: @贝壳-BeiKe sometimes it will. What you expect from echo  "<option...", where should it printed? in select tag? where is that?

Comment: @arkascha those echoes work fine, on the page that works http://lookupblue.com/adm/update.php  yes it really shows nothing at all... view-source:http://lookupblue.com/adm/latest.php

Comment: OK, then you should either start using a debugger (`xdebug` is easy to get started with) or you have to begin the cumbersome and annoying way of manual debugging by inserting some debug output after more or less every line of code and checking what happens, step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but you have many problems in your code, it must be something like this. It will print multiple input type and one select option if that is what you are trying to have

```
<?php
    require 'dor.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * from Pages where ID = 10";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = array();
?>
<form>
<?php
    $options = '';     
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['PTitle']) && $_POST['PTitle'] == $row['id']) 
        {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
        } 
        else 
        {
            $selected = '';
        }
        $options.='<option '.$selected.' value="'.$row["PType"].'">'.$row["PTitle"].', '.$row["PType"].', '.$row["PContent"].', '.$row["POrder"].', '.$row["PTitle"].'</option>';

?>
Name: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['PTitle']; ?>"/> </br> 
<?php
    }
?>  
<select><?php echo $options; ?></select>
</form>
```

Comment: This still echos the `<option>`s before the `<form>` and without a `<select>`, which results in invalid html code.

Comment: yeah it will, I dont know what OP is trying so a working script may be give them a lead. I will edit though

Comment: @Sean did you see where I edited the original post to show what I thought you meant by the options are before the form? Right now if I could just get the title that would be a big help. Or does the order I populate the fields matter?

Comment: @贝壳-BeiKe edited answer, it will print multiple input type and one select option. Hope that help

Comment: @SameerJain That was closer, but it brought all the options in a field together. http://lookupblue.com/adm/help.php I was going to try to fix it, but thought it best to show you before I make it worse. Thanks again!

Comment: Like I said, not sure what you are trying to achieve. I guess you have a working script now and you can play with it :-)

Comment: @SameerJain True, my biggest confusion sometimes is WHERE not what. Now I understand WHERE to put stuff.

Comment: @贝壳-BeiKe Also make sure you think HOW the code will execute. Good luck